# Non fullscreen View Controller force rotation IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, rotation, addsubview

I have one view, which is fullscreen. I want to add to this view another view of my VC. When I add this VC view as subview to to fullscreen view I need to rotate this view to landscape. My VC has methods for forced rotation, but the view isn't displayed in preferred interface orientation, it is displayed in portrait. I would like to know, if there is a way how to achieve force rotation when adding a view as subview?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is a little unclear - do you mean you want to keep the view of your main VC in portrait always while this child VC's view is in landscape always? Or is their rotation that needs to happen when the device is rotated?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't.
You can apply a transform to a view to rotate it.

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
```